# Why does updating Chrome pop up a UAC window

Tags: google-chrome

Suddenly updating Chrome on one of my machines is popping up a UAC window. I have a similar machine where this is not happening and I assume that this is not proper behavior.

Windows 7 , service pack 1. Chrome version 40.0.2214.115 m. This version was automatically installed last month with no issue.

Any ideas what could cause this?

Comment: Go on right click *properties* on the google icon, *properties* then *compatibility*.  the option *run this program as administrator* is checked?

Comment: No it is not checked.